# yii2 JOIN doesn't return correct id value in GridView

Tags: php, mysql, join, yii2

i'm not getting the correct id, i got id's with values **0,1,2,3**
if i will not specify the join query above, the id returns correct
but if i will specify the joins of the two other tables, it will return erroneous id
**this is the gridview**

```
echo GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'columns' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

                'type',

                'name',
                'gsm',
                'email',
                'w_exp',
                'course',

                ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
            ],
        ]);
```

**this is the search model function**

```
public function search($params)
        {

            $query = RegTab::find()

            ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'train_tab', 'train_tab.id = reg_tab.training')
              ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'type_tab', 'type_tab.id = train_tab.type')
            ->select(['reg_tab.id as id','reg_tab.f_name as name', 
                    'reg_tab.gsm as gsm','reg_tab.email as email', 'reg_tab.w_exp as w_exp', 
                    'train_tab.course as course']);

            $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
                'query' => $query,
            ]);
```

i'm not getting the correct id, i got id's with values **0,1,2,3**
if i will not specify the join query above, the id returns correct
but if i will specify the joins of the two other tables, it will return erroneous id

Comment: To debug, get the sql with `$query->createCommand()->getSql()` and run it into your MySQL. Check whether that is the query you want or not.

Comment: Where are you showing the ID as I cannot see any place you do that, are you sure you are not looking at the serial column and thinking this is the ID?